# Boinc server does not send work

Tags: templates, schedule, boinc

I am new to boinc server and I am running into issues while following this guide to configure the uppercase application.

https://wiki.debian.org/BOINC/ServerGuide/WorkUnitGeneration

It appears everything is running normal as the status page shows all processes are running. However, when I connect a boinc client, the client does not download any work. The scheduler logs from the server show this. The status page also shows 12 units of work ready to send.

```
2013-12-19 17:30:09.3390 [PID=6887 ] Request: [USER#1] [HOST#1] [IP 10.0.2.16] client 7.2.7
2013-12-19 17:30:09.3480 [PID=6887 ] Sending reply to [HOST#1]: 0 results, delay req 7.00
2013-12-19 17:30:09.3480 [PID=6887 ] Scheduler ran 0.013 seconds
```

I might have the templates or work creation off as I don't understand how those pieces are connected and what's required in the template files.

Comment: What does the feeder log say?

Comment: Could you show the other files you have created?